# rewrite rules with apache does not work

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try to make specific rewrite rules by .htaccess but i need help, its doesn't work.

This is my url :
    **http://mywebsite.net/aaa-bbbb/cccc**

aaa = dynamic parameter ( [a-z] )
bbb = dynamic parameter ( [a-z] )
cccc = dynamic parameter but optionnal ( [a-z] )

And i want rewrite user to this url : 
http://mywebsite.net/mydir/ccc?x=aaa&y=bbbb**

url still will http://mywebsite.net/aaa-bbbb/cccc on tabbar

i try this
    **RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ mydir/$3 [L]**

but it doesn't work

thx !

Comment: And "but it doesn't work" means what exactly? Do you get an error? Is the redirection wrong? Does nothing happen at all? Does the universe implode?

Comment: And your http servers error log file contains what entry for that request?

Comment: first i have 404 "GET /sdsds-test/sdqsd HTTP/1.1" 404 13617 and 200 "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 7770 "http://mywebsite.net/sdsds-test/sdqsd" but i m not on good page

Comment: You posted the entries in the _access_ log file, not the _error_ log file. I tried to write a general answer below, though.

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite a request to

```
http://mywebsite.net/aaa-bbbb/cccc
```

internally to

```
/mydir/ccc?x=aaa&y=bbbb
```

you need such a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ /mydir/$3?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
```

Note: the above rule has the syntax to be used inside the http servers host configuration. If you really want to use a `.htaccess` style file instead you need to use a slightly modified syntax, since those files work on *relative* paths:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ mydir/$3?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
```

You can spot the missing `/` in the rewrite goal. The `.htaccess` style file has to reside inside the folder holding the `mydir` folder for this to work. Also the interpretation of such files has to be enabled at all in the http server configuration for.

---

A general note: `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they *really* slow down the http server for nothing. They are only offered as a last option for those *not* having access to the http servers host configuration. So for example for cheat shared hosting providers. In general you should *always* prefer to place such rules inside the host configuration itself.